# Adding“last modified” and “created” column in SQLite/SpatiaLite table

Tags: spatialite, database-design

I am designing a new db schema for a SQLite/SpatiaLite database.

Each table should get two extra columns called modified and created which should be automatically change as soon a row gets inserted or updated.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please edit your post so it contains your prior research and trials, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in triggers, you can see https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/sqlite-triggers.php

Comment: Thank you pasqal!